# Heatmap with rrweb package

Tags: hotjar, session-replay

Is there a way I can implement the heatmap feature on top of [rrweb](https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb) library like how hotjar does theirs?

Comment: Have you found the answer ?
Im also looking for the same.